# Callback - Access constraints matrix coefficients

Tags: callback, cplex, julia-jump

I am solving integer linear programms with JuMP 0.21.1 and CPLEX. I  am using a callback to add user cuts. Inside this callback I would like to access the following information:

- number of constraints (which varies as I add user cuts);
- number of variables;
- value of the coefficients of the constraint matrix;
- value of the coefficients of the constraints right-hand-side.

I could use global variables to get these information but it would deteriorate the performances as these values are not constant (the number of constraints increases when I add user cuts).

In the JuMP documentation it is specified that the only information I can get is the current value of the variables and that if I need anything else, I must create a solver-dependent callback.

I have seen the GLPK callback in [the documentation](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/blob/master/examples/callbacks.jl) but it does not really help me. I also found the [cplex_callback.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl/blob/master/src/cpx_callbacks.jl) in the CPLEX.jl github repository which seems promising as there is a function "setcallbackcut" which contains an argument rhs among others. However, I don't know how to use it...

Could you tell me how I could do? Or where I could find examples?

Comment: I am not sure whether CPLEX can provide the information you need: cuts are only added to the *presolved* model, so the best you could get would be the data for the presolved model. The presolved model however is very different from the original model and unless your callbacks operates in the presolved space (I don't even know if JuMP supports that) you will have trouble to relate this to the original model. What do you plan to do with this information? Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Comment: The presolve model would be ok. I am adding generic cuts which can be applied on any constraint matrix.

If I use a global non constant array for the constraints matrix would it lead to bad performances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using the solver-dependent callback of CPLEX with user-cuts.

https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl/blob/5ae4628446470fa0a46438cdfe577155dbcfd54c/test/MathOptInterface/MOI_callbacks.jl#L336-L366

Note that CPLEX.jl just wraps CPLEX's C API, so you are limited to what it can do. Here is the documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/hpMIPcallbacks.html

In particular, you should be careful with respect to

> number of constraints (which varies as I add user cuts)

because there is no guarantee that CPLEX will add the cut you provide. Why do you need the coefficients and RHS terms in the callback?

Note that to avoid using global variables, just wrap everything in a function to create a closure. For example, in the following it is fine to access and modify the variable `calls` inside the callback.

```
function build_and_run_model()
    # ...
    calls = 0
    function my_callback(cb_data, cb_where)
        calls += 1
        # ...
    end
    # ...
end
```

Comment: The closure will solve my problem, thanks! I need the coefficients in the callback as I compute cuts which are based on linear combination of the constraints.